# Neo4j not saving Label correctly

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I am using Spring to add some nodes into my neo4j database.  When I save a 'Person' node, I notice that it gets saved twice.  Once as a "Person" and another time as a "_Person".

Anyone know why that is?

Comment: Can you share the code that you're using to save those entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the documented and expected behaviour. RTFM (read the fine manual) at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_typerepresentationstrategy :

> Each node gets labeled with its type and all supertypes and interfaces that are also @NodeEntity-annotated. There is a special Label prefixed with _ that represents the current type of the entity.